# How to create hash of array in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have a data like this

```
Group AT1G01040-TAIR-G
        LOC_Os03g02970 69%
Group AT1G01050-TAIR-G
        LOC_Os10g26600 85%
        LOC_Os10g26633 35%
Group AT1G01090-TAIR-G
        LOC_Os04g02900 74%
```

How can  create the data structure that looks like this:

```
print Dumper \%big;

$VAR = { "Group AT1G01040-TAIR-G" => ['LOC_Os03g02970 69%'],
         "Group AT1G01050-TAIR-G" => ['LOC_Os10g26600 85%','LOC_Os10g26633 35%'],
         "Group AT1G01090-TAIR-G" => ['LOC_Os04g02900 74%']};
```

This is my attempt, but fail:

```
my %big;
while ( <> ) {
    chomp;
    my $line = $_;
    my $head = "";
    my @temp;

    if ( $line =~ /^Group/ ) {
        $head = $line;
        $head =~ s/[\r\s]+//g;
        @temp = ();


    }
    elsif ($line =~ /^\t/){
        my $cont = $line;
           $cont =~ s/[\t\r]+//g;
        push @temp, $cont;

        push @{$big{$head}},@temp;
    };

}
```

Comment: why not produce a hash of arrays as hashes? So your datastructure becomes like: `Group AT1G01040-TAIR-G" => [{'LOC_Os03g02970' = > 69}]` (in case you need to do some calculation with them, or store them in a xml or...?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
my %big;
my $currentGroup;

while (my $line = <> ) {
    chomp $line;

    if ( $line =~ /^Group/ ) {
        $big{$line} = $currentGroup = [];
    }
    elsif ($line =~ s/^\t+//) {
        push @$currentGroup, $line;
    }
}
```

You should probably add some additional error checking to this, e.g. an `else` clause to warn about lines that don't match either regex.  Also, check to see if `$currentGroup` is `undef` before pushing (in case the first line begins with a tab instead of "Group").

The biggest problem with your original code is that you're declaring and initializing `$head` and `@temp` *inside* the loop, which means they got reset on every line.  Variables that need to persist across lines have to be declared outside the loop, as I've done with `$currentGroup`.

I'm not quite sure what you're intending to accomplish with the `s/[\r\s]+//g;` bit.  `\r` is included in `\s`, so that means the same as `s/\s+//g;` (which would strip all whitespace), but your desired result hash includes whitespace in your keys.  If you want to strip trailing whitespace, you need to include an anchor:  `s/\s+\z//`.

Comment: I think I would do the same but also make a reference out of %big. (`$big->{$line}`) It took my Perl masters a lot of time to teach/beat me until I understood them but cant live without them anymore I'm now trying to convince my current colleagues.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't want to give you an answer, so I'll just tell you to look at:

- [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)
- [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)

Well, there ya go :-).

Comment: +1 for perlreftut, one of the most useful docs in all of perldoc!

Comment: Thanks @Joel. I found it very useful in learning to use References in Perl.

Comment: That comment got me to thinking about my favorite perldocs and I made a little [blog post](http://joelslinux.blogspot.com/2011/08/learning-perl-from-perldoc.html) about some it.

Comment: @Joel: Nice blog post! Though I would say you need to read more than just those three Perldocs to learn Perl.

Answer (score 1):

Your pushing arrays to your hash item. You should just be pushing the values. (You don't need `@temp` at all.)

```
push @{$big{$head}}, $cont;
```

Also `$head` must be declared outside your loop, otherwise it looses its value after each iteration.